# Seaborn heatmap change size of colorbar

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

With the following code I plot a seaborn heatmap together with a colorbar.
I want to set the size of the colorbar equal to the size of the heatmap.
How can I achieve this?

I have tried to adress the colorbar using `fig.colorbar(heatmap)` but this returns the error:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'
```

Code:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(30,60))

cmap = plt.get_cmap('inferno',30)
cmap.set_under('white')#Colour values less than vmin in white
cmap.set_over('yellow')# colour valued larger than vmax in red 

Crosstab=50000*np.random.randn(10,10)

heatmap=sns.heatmap(Crosstab[::-1],cmap=cmap,annot=False,square=True,ax=ax,vmin=1,vmax=50000,linewidths=0.8,linecolor="grey")



plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I have checked this answer before. Problem seems to be that I am using sns.heatmap() and not plt.anything(). But I don't know how to fix this

Comment: Can you create a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the MCVE. The code you have given works fine for me, the colorbar is the same height as the graph. What version of matplotlib/seaborn are you using?

Comment: I am using Seaborn in Version 0.7.1 and Matplotlib in Version 2.0.2

Comment: If you show me how I can (taking my question as example) in general change the size of the colorbar --> For instance, show an example in which you change the size based on my example, I can adjust the size by myself.

Comment: I have added an answer. Since looking at this more I do sometimes see a colorbar bigger than the plot. Though this was when I was messing around with the figure size. My answer should provide a work around

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As said in the comments, I cannot reproduce this issue using Seaborn version 0.8 and matplotlib 2.1.1, therefore if possible I would recommend updating the modules.

That being said, you can manipulate the size of the colorbar using the `cbar_kws` argument in [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html). This needs to be a dictionary which is passed (under the hood) as kwargs to matplotlibs [`fig.colorbar()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar).

One kwarg of interest is the `shrink` parameter. This shrinks the size of the colorbar:

> *shrink*:
>   1.0; fraction by which to multiply the size of the colorbar

The default *should* be 1.0, so you could try manually setting this to 1. However, if this does not work you can shrink the colorbar more by using a lower value. This may require some tinkering in order to get the colorbar the right size.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cmap = plt.get_cmap('inferno',30)
cmap.set_under('white')#Colour values less than vmin in white
cmap.set_over('yellow')# colour valued larger than vmax in red

Crosstab=50000*np.random.randn(10,10)

heatmap=sns.heatmap(Crosstab[::-1],cmap=cmap,annot=False,square=True,ax=ax,vmin=1,vmax=50000,
                    cbar_kws={"shrink": 0.5},linewidths=0.8,linecolor="grey")

plt.show()
```

Giving:

[image]

Comment: what if the colorbar has too much padding and there's a big gap between the label and the right border of the figure?

Answer (score 4):

To follow up on DavidG's very useful answer and Yuca's question (apologies, I can't comment):

If you have multiple cbar_kws, it can be useful to supply the cbar_kws via a dictionary constructed from name=value pairs.

E.g. A common cbar_kws dict that I use for seaborn heatmaps:

`cbar_kws=dict(use_gridspec=False,location="bottom",pad=0.01,shrink=0.25)`

Here, Yuca could do the following to shrink the cbar and change the padding (try a few pad values to see which one looks best):
`cbar_kws=dict(shrink=0.5,pad=0.01)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the figure proportions.  Instead of declaring...

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,60))
```

...try keeping the proportions even:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,30))
```

That worked for me.